# To check continuity of Multivariable function at origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

GIVEN$ F (x, y) = x^{2} + y^{2} / x + y ,$ when x+y is not equal to 0

```
           = 0    , when x+y =0
```

is it enough to say here that when approaching from line y=-x limit does not exist ? Or do i ned to show something else.

Comment: That depends on whether you mean $f$ is continuous on its domain, or continuous on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski continuity at origin

Comment: Obviously, the limit exists when approaching from line $y=-x$

Comment: Right. I don't think approaching $0$ from that line is valid. Better to use an $\epsilon-\delta$ to show that there are points $(x,y)$ which are arbitrarily close to $0$, whose image under $g$ is no closer to $0$ than some $\epsilon$.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski how did you get idea of its continuity ordiscontinuity before proceeding like in thisquestion

Comment: Well lets see what $f$ when $(x,y)$ approaches the line $y=x$. Let's let $(x,y)$ approach along the line $y=x+c$ for some constant $c$. The two lines intersect when $x=-c/2$. Substituting $y=x+c$ into $f$ and simplifying gives $\frac{2x^2+2cx+c^2}{2x+c}$. Letting $x\to (-c/2)^+$ we see that the numerator approaches $c^2/2$ and the denominator approaches $0$.  So, $\lim{x\to (-c/2)^+}\frac{2x^2+2cx+c^2}{2x+c}=\infty$.

Comment: couple of typos: let's see what $f$ does when $(x,y)$ approaches the line $y=-x$.